# Intersection of powers of ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. Let $I, J \subseteq R$ be ideals. Show that for every integer $i$, there is an integer $N > i$ such that $I^N\cap J^N\subseteq (I\cap J)^i$.

I believe I have to use the Artin-Rees lemma, but cannot find the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induction over $i$. For $i=0$ or $i=1$ this is clear. Else, assume we have found $M$ such that $I^M \cap J^M \subseteq (I \cap J)^{i-1}$. Now, by Artin-Rees we find $k_1 \geq 1$ such that for $l_1 \geq k_1$ we have

$I^{l_1}(I^M \cap J^M) = I^{l_1-k_1}(I^{M+k_1} \cap J^M)$

in particular

$I^{k_1}(I^M \cap J^M)= I^{M+k_1} \cap J^M$

Similarly, we find $k_2$ such that for $l_2 \geq k_2$ we have

$J^{l_2}(I^{M+k_1} \cap J^M) = J^{l_2-k_2}(I^{M+k_1} \cap J^{M+k_2})$

and hence

$(I^{M+k_1} \cap J^{M+k_2})=I^{k_1}J^{k_2}(I^M \cap J^M)\subseteq IJ (I \cap J)^{i-1} \subseteq (I \cap J)^i$

Answer (score 4):

By the Artin-Rees Lemma there is a $q\ge0$ such that $p\ge0$ implies 
$$
I^{p+q}\cap J^i=I^p(I^q\cap J^i).
$$ 
This gives 
$$
I^{i+q}\cap J^{i+q}\subset I^{i+q}\cap J^i=I^i(I^q\cap J^i)\subset I^iJ^i=(IJ)^i\subset(I\cap J)^i.
$$